# How can I simulate uc3854 based circuit

Tags: simulation

I want to design pfc boost converter using uc3854 but I am not getting its simulation model also on texas TINA ti library. Where can I simulate it?

Comment: Many components do not have a simulation model. If it is not listed on TI's website then it probably does not exist.

Comment: You might try building it yourself using the Functional Block Diagram. But it may take quite some time carefully reading all the details of the datasheet (if even provided...) and testing getting your model close to reality.

Comment: Note the UC3854A is a better choice today; more accurate and needs less external components.